# Matlab: How to read commented portion of ascii file

Tags: matlab, comments, text-parsing

I have an ascii file whose first couple hundred lines are commented (followed by the data) that give some information about the data. For example these are couple of lines I snipped out from large number of lines which are commented:
[image]

Right now I am only reading the data without comments by using `load` as:

```
filename = uigetfile('*.dat', 'Select Input data');
Data = load(filename, '-ascii');
```

How can I read the commented lines (which end just before the data starts) and pick some comments out of all comments based on some identifications such as **Program name and version**, **Creation date** etc. ?

Comment: I'm a little confused about your file format. Does every other line start with a comment or did you just annotate the lines here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the lines into a cell array:

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
C = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
C = C{:};  %// Flatten cell array
fclose(fid);
```

Now you can use [`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to manipulate the textual data. For instance, to find the comment lines that contain the string "Creation date", you can do this:

```
idx = ~cellfun('isempty', regexp(C, "^\s*%.*Creation date"));
```

where "`^\s*%` matches the percent sign (`%`) at the beginning of the line along with any  leading whitespace, and the `.*` matches any number of characters until the occurrence of "Creation date". Needless to say, you can adjust the [regular expression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html) pattern to your liking.

The resulting variable `idx` stores a logical (*i.e* boolean) vector with "1"s at the positions of the lines matching the pattern (you can obtain their explicit numerical indices with `find(idx)`). Next you can filter those lines with `C(idx)` or iterate over them with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
fid = fopen(filename); 
nHeaderRows = 412; 
headerCell = cell(nHeaderRows, 1); 
for i=1:nHeaderRows 
    headerCell{i} = fgets(fid); 
end 
headerText = char(headerCell);
```